# extending Wpf MouseButtonEventArgs to enable custom args

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

when any event handler is created there is no option i know of that i could pass my own argument to the event handler.

for example `MouseDown` event,

```
void TxblckLineNum_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff with e ...
}
```

i need to pass some more properties within the `e` parameter so i have tried to derive from various `EventArgs` classes and i couldn't use any of them as `e`

what is the best approach for passing some extra data into the event handler ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TxblckLine.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler((s, e) => TxblckLineNum_MouseDown(s, e, SomePar, SomeOtherPar));


void TxblckLineNum_MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, string SomePar, int SomeOtherPar)
{
    //do stuff with SomePar / SomeOtherPar...
}
```